# HandlebarsJS date format

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I have a JSON file which returns multiple items with different values for concert dates.

So this value returns:

```
date: "2014-11-27"
```

and in my `HandlebarsJS`-template I have:

```
<p>{{date}}</p>
```

but I want to display the date like this:

```
NOV 27
```

by using `HandlebarsJS` and yes, I have MomentJS included too.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could register a Handlebars helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('formatDate', function(dateString) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(
        moment(dateString).format("MMM D").toUpperCase()
    );
});
```

After registering you have to change your template:

```
<p>{{formatDate date}}</p>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/limond/m6eyo98b/)

Comment: If you need various formats then you can make this: ... function(dateString, format) { return new Handlebars.SafeString(
        moment(dateString).format(format).toUpperCase()
    ); } and then call it with {{formatDate date "DD.MM.YYYY"}}